# Why do `sort | sed '1,5p'` and `sort | head -n 5` behave differently when pipefail is in use?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, pipe, head

there is a different strange behavior,when it comes to pipe.

bash --version

GNU bash, version 4.4.20

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
```

**test A**

```
    set -eux
    set -o pipefail
    
    ps aux | tail -n +2 | sort -k 3 -n -r | head -n 5 #the shell will exit after some times
```

**test B**

```
    set -eux
    set -o pipefail
    
    ps aux | tail -n +2 | sort -k 3 -n -r | sed -n "1,5p" #the shell will never exit however often I issue it
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce, they both exit as expected.

Comment: Mind, `set -e` [is a bad idea in the first place](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: Also see [Bash Pitfalls #60 (set -euo pipefail)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#set_-euo_pipefail).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what should be put at first place in a bash script?

Comment: @0stone0 you can try more times.see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Answer (score 3):

From what I see, `head` closes the stdin (respectively terminates) after 5 lines have been read. If `sort` at this time is not done yet with feeding its result into the pipe, the stdout for `sort` is broken, and `sort` terminates with a non-zero exitcode. Since you have turned on *pipefail*, this generates a non-zero exitcode for the whole pipe. Since you also have turned on *-e*, this kills your shell.

OTOH, `sed` consumes the whole standard input. Therefore, `sort` can stuff everythin into its stdout and no pipe breaks.

Comment: Of course, the `sed` behavior described is characteristic of the particular `sed` expression used.  I would generally be inclined to use `sed 5q` instead of `sed -n 1,5p`, but I expect the former to exhibit the same effect on the overall pipeline as `head -n 5`.

Comment: so,in which case I should use head, and in which other cases I should use sed instead?

Comment: @focuszheng : Both is fine. You just shouldn't use `set -e`. But this is what Charles Duffy and pjh told you. I just explained in my answer the difference in your two commands, as this is what you had asked.

Comment: in this case, sed is preferable,as it never make pipe broken

Comment: @focuszheng : In your case, `sed` is certainly fine. In the general case - if you have a huge input -, `sed` may take considerably longer, because it needs to read the whole file, while `head` only needs to read the requested number fo lines.